# Not automatically printed out data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table) 
version 1.9.4
estim <- data.table(aa=c(1,2,3), vvat1at=c(1,5,16))

checked=TRUE
```

If had some check  and it is TRUE ,then in variable estim create new variable a with value 1.

```
if (checked) estim[, a:=1]
```

But automatically printed out data.table.

```
        aa  vat1at    a
   1:   1       1     1
   2:   2       5     1
   3:   3      16     1
```

Can some something to do that not printed out this data.table when I not wanted?

Comment: you can wrap it in `invisible` : `invisible(if (checked) estim[, a:=1] )`

Comment: Or simply : if (checked) x <- estim[, a:=1]

Comment: Jur, we're aware of this, and Matt's working on it. Could you please file an issue [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) so that we don't miss it.. Thanks!