# In data.table checking print out data

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table) 
# version 1.9.4
data <- data.table(v=c(2,2,3))

data[v<1, v:=3]
```

If checking is `FALSE`, then print out all `data.table`.

```
        v
   1:   2
   2:   2
   3:   3
```

Can some something to do that not printed out this `data.table` when I not needed?

And second problem is

```
  data <- data.table(v=c(2,2,3,4,5,7))
  data[, v2:=ifelse(v>=2 & v<8, 1, NA)]

  Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:

   $ v : num  2 2 3 4 5 7
   $ v2: num  1 1 1 NA NA NA
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

In previous case I have error, when checking in character type data with numeric.

```
  data[, v2:=ifelse(v>=4 & v<8, 2, NA)]
  data[v2==2]

Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: v, v2, v2_text
```

Comment: wrap it in `invisible()`

Comment: Either this Q or your other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255760/not-automaticaly-printed-out-data-table) has got to be a duplicate..?